# Generate link to a page with specific language

Tags: joomla-3.x, multilingual, router

Lets say I have a menu pointing to an article translated to both english and spanish.

How can I generate a link to the english page from the spanish translation?

I want to put a notice in all the spanish articles saying for example:

```
<p>
    There is an english version for this article <a href="index.php?Itemid=1086">here</a>
</p>
```

If this article gets loaded in spanish the link will point to the spanish article instead of the english article.

Comment: So you don't have an English article and a Spanish article -- you have one article and you want Joomla to switch the article language?

Comment: Have you tried using the article button below your editor?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a multilingual site and your articles are associated, enable `Show Associations` option in `com_content` configuration.